# Error when installing wubi on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, wubi

Im installing ubuntu on windows 7(wubi 11.10):

when its nearly done it gives me this error in the log file:

```
Usage: /cygdrive/c/Users/Psao/AppData/Local/Temp/pyl10D2.tmp/bin/resize2fs.exe -f C:/ubuntu/disks/root.disk 17744M [-d debug_flags] [-f] [-F] [-p] device [new_size]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 461, in expand_diskimage
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\utils.py", line 66, in run_command
Exception: Error executing command
>>command=C:\Users\P'sao\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl10D2.tmp\bin\resize2fs.exe -f C:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk 17744M
>>retval=1
>>stderr=
>>stdout=resize2fs 1.40.6 (09-Feb-2008)
Usage: /cygdrive/c/Users/Psao/AppData/Local/Temp/pyl10D2.tmp/bin/resize2fs.exe -f C:/ubuntu/disks/root.disk 17744M [-d debug_flags] [-f] [-F] [-p] device [new_size]


10-25 20:31 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
10-25 20:31 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
10-25 20:31 ERROR  root: Error executing command
>>command=C:\Users\P'sao\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl10D2.tmp\bin\resize2fs.exe -f C:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk 17744M
>>retval=1
>>stderr=
>>stdout=resize2fs 1.40.6 (09-Feb-2008)
Usage: /cygdrive/c/Users/Psao/AppData/Local/Temp/pyl10D2.tmp/bin/resize2fs.exe -f C:/ubuntu/disks/root.disk 17744M [-d debug_flags] [-f] [-F] [-p] device [new_size]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 132, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 461, in expand_diskimage
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\utils.py", line 66, in run_command
Exception: Error executing command
>>command=C:\Users\P'sao\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl10D2.tmp\bin\resize2fs.exe -f C:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk 17744M
>>retval=1
>>stderr=
>>stdout=resize2fs 1.40.6 (09-Feb-2008)
Usage: /cygdrive/c/Users/Psao/AppData/Local/Temp/pyl10D2.tmp/bin/resize2fs.exe -f C:/ubuntu/disks/root.disk 17744M [-d debug_flags] [-f] [-F] [-p] device [new_size]
```

can some one help me?

Comment: You have adequate free space?

Comment: yes,I'm giving it 30 gigs of my 300 gigs left on my hardrive.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the ' in the file names (ie your user name).  Notice the command line is different than the error for your name.